# combining websockets and http

Tags: http, websocket

I'm creating a program that wants to show statistics.
For that I decided to use websockets and http. Websockets because it requires no polling but allows my server to push any changes (I'm open for suggestions for different solutions) so quick updates. For websockets I use the websocket++ library and for http I use libmicrohttpd.
The program runs on Unix/Linux systems.

Now using websocket++ creating the websockets is simple. I let the user decide on a portnumber and that's that. Same thing for http using libmicrohttpd.
The problem now is, how can I point from html to that websocket service?
I only know a portnumber (that listens on all network interfaces; it binds to 0.0.0.0) and not a hostname. I tried http://:8001/ (so without any hostname, or ip address) but at least firefox doesn't take that.
So how can I resolve that?
I could in theory let websocket++ do the http handling but that doesn't work for binary files like images and it also does not let you process HEAD-requests.

Comment: To make a connection from a client to ANY server, you need an IP address AND a port number.  And, the server needs to be listening for the connection on that specific port number.  I don't know why you'd let the end user pick the port number.  That doesn't make much architectural sense to me.  Design for one port number and let different users use rooms or channels on that one port which makes a logical way to keep their traffic separte.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

An http-request has (usually - tried with chrome & firefox) an "Host:"-header. E.g.:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: keetweej.vanheusden.com:8000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0
```

So what I do now is cut the hostname from the Host-record and add the portnumber of the websockets to it.
This works!

Answer (score 0):

> I only know a portnumber (that listens on all network interfaces; it binds to 0.0.0.0) and not a hostname. I tried http://:8001/ (so without any hostname, or ip address) but at least firefox doesn't take that.

Thats not possible to let a webbrowser search for a specified webpage at a specified port, because you have more than million webserver addresses (you cannot not know at all) to search for a open port.
So the only very solution would be to provide an url in the html you mentioned above a script can use to connect to your service.

If you want to bind to localhost (127.0.0.1): `http://localhost:8001/` or `http://127.0.0.1:8001/`

Comment: Well it is on the same server as the http server. Localhost is not an option as it could be setup internet facing.